# Updating label captions of subreports

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

In Report_Open() sub on the main report I have:

```
SQLstring = "Select * from dbo_NewPatient where id=49"
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Now I want to update a Label caption in a subreport, On my subreport I have tried:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Labal1.Caption = Me.Parent.rs("index")

End Sub
```

But Me.Parent.rs("index") doesn't work, I've tried multple iterations of the Me!, Me.[ and things like that, but can't seem to find what the syntax should be.  How would i update this Label1.Caption?

I'm going to have multiple subreports, so that's why I have the SQL command on the main report, I didn't want to have to call the SQL command on each subreport.

Thanks for any help or direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your intention is with the Recordset, you haven't shown any code that *does something* with it.

If your intention is to set the `Recordset` property of the (main) Report then I don't believe this will work:

```
Me.Recordset = rs
```

The Help system is not very clear about this, but when this is attempted Access displays an error stating that this feature is only available in ADP (a defunct technology).

I would set the `RecordSource` property of the Report to your sql-statement:

```
Me.RecordSource = sqlString
```

Alternatively, you can set this to "SELECT * FROM dbo_NewPatient" and use the id of 49 as a `Filter`.

If the "index" on the main form is in the Detail section, then you cannot refer to it directly from your subreport. Add a hidden textbox to, perhaps, the main report's `ReportHeader` that refers to the control in the Detail section:

```
=[txtIndex]
```

In the subreport's Open even you can refer to this control, assuming it is named "txtIndex_ref":

```
Label1.Caption = Me.Parent.Controls("txtIndex_ref")
```

Comment: This is what I've done for now.  I just can't stand the fact that I've created a hidden textbox, just for this purpose. Oh well.

Comment: Yes, it is a pain. I've often had to do this. Hint: Make sure you rename all the controls, as Access is easily confused between field and control-names. I also painted these *referential* textboxes yellow, even though they remain hidden, so that they stand out in Design View.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare a Public var ..

```
Public rs As Recordset '--------

SQLstring = "Select * from dbo_NewPatient where id=49"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLstring, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

So you can do

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    lblIndex.Caption = rs("index")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, thought I get an error "Invalid attribute in Sub or Function", highlighting the word "Public"....I'm assuming I can declare a public variable in my Report_Open() function?

Comment: Public variables should be defined outside of any specific procedure, at the top of the report's module.

Comment: @russds .. you should declare it in module level .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx